# TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, tuple found

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, tuples

I want to write the content of html

```
html = ' '.join(html)
    html_file = open(diff_path, "w")
    html_file.write(html)
    html_file.close()
```

but i'm getting this error on the first line shared although `html = ' '.join(html)` should have fixed that.

```
typeError: sequence item 1: expected string, tuple found
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Well, obviously `html` isn't a list of strings.  Why not look at it so you can see what you're dealing with, then decide how you want to handle it?

Comment: What is `html`? Are you getting this back from a database query? Show `print(html)`.

Comment: html is a tuple but it should be a string.

Comment: It seems like html is a list of tuples. The join method only works on a list of strings.

Comment: @Alex html is likely a sequence of tuples instead of a list of strings, it may or may not be a tuple itself, because you can pass a tuple to `join` provided that it contains strings.

Comment: Fair, any clue on what measures i can take to get list of strings instead of tuples.

Comment: @Alex The first thing you need to do is show the output of `print(html)` as I asked in my first comment. We're just guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert into string 
try below:

```
html = " ".join(str(html))
```

Comment: nope it's not that simple because i need the output to stay in html format.

Comment: This almost certainly doesn't do what the OP wanted.

Comment: What does HTML tuple contains? Print  that tuple & write the expected output as well.